# nsmutablearray - Componentsseperatedbystring

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How wouold i do this with a nsmutablearray, its simple with a nsarray just not a mutable array

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create mutable array from non-mutable that you get from that message:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:...]];
```

Comment: You are missing a `*`. Also `-mutableCopy` is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
NSArray *array = [someString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
```

use the mutArray, this is one NSMutableArray object.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work too:

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = (NSMutableArray *)[yourString 
                               componentsSeparatedByString:@"separator"];
```

You might need to `retain` and `release` when you're done.

Comment: That's a terrible idea -- never cast an immutable object to a mutable version.